# Related forms in Yii

Tags: php, forms, yii, orm, relationship

I trying to embed related form fields to my main form. But I get exception `Array to string conversion`. I think thats because I establish a HAS_MANY relation. Because when relation HAS_ONE, form works properly. So how can i get the fields from table(model) with HAS_MANY relation.
Here is relations:

User model:

```
'address' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Address', 'user_id'),
```

Address model:

```
'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'user_id'),
```

Part of form:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model->address,'phone'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model->address,'phone',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>255)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'phone'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: HAS_MANY return multidimensional array.ex. `array(0=>array('phone'=>'xyz'));`. Try to use like `$model->address[0]`

Comment: Displays an error: `Undefined offset: 0`

Comment: Can you please add dump of address array using `var_dump($model->address)` in question. It will help to understand what it return.

Answer (score 1):

The relation `HAS_MANY` will create a array of address in your user model.

> Declaring relationship in AR involves overriding the relations()
>   method of CActiveRecord. The method returns an array of relationship
>   configurations. Each array element represents a single relationship
>   with the following format:

So, if you want all the Address from your User, you use the `$model->address` like this:

```
$allAddress = $model->address;
foreach($allAddress in $address){
//@address =  New Address()
//Do some stuff here with your address
}
```

But if you are creating a NEW User, and ADD a new Address for your User, then create the user before than address.

```
$UserModel = new User();
$UserModel->attribute = $userData;
$UserModel->Save();

$AddressModel-> new Address();
$AddressModel->attribute = $addressData;
$AddressModel->user_id = $userModel->id;
$AddressModel->save();

$AddressModel2-> new Address();
$AddressModel2->attribute = $addressData2;
$AddressModel2->user_id = $userModel->id;
$AddressModel2->save();
```

For more information about relations in yii, read [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#declaring-relationship).

For creating a form with more than one Model, look [this article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/19/how-to-use-a-single-form-to-collect-data-for-two-or-more-models/).